# jquery with external php remaining time counter. More than one execution

Tags: php, jquery

Want to do following:

1) Each 3 minutes jquery starts to execute, goes to external php, checks session values

2) goes back (from external php) and shows remaining time counter

After first 3 minutes all works as expected. But after second 3 minutes, i get as if `function updateClock ( )` executes 2 times, after third 3 minutes, as if executes 3 times and so on.

How to reset `$('#remaining_time').html()` on each execution? Tried in external php insert javascript like `?> <script type="text/javascript">$('#remaining_time').html('');</script> <?php`, but it does not help. On each execution i want to reset remaining time counter.

Here is code (part of code)

Html

```
<div class="div_show_hide" id="logout_warning_popup">

 <div class="" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; bottom:0; background: rgba(199,199,199,0.9); display: table; ">

  <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align:center;">

   <span style="align:center; width:200px; height:200px; border:solid 0px red; background:#fff; padding:20px;">
   Session will expire after <span id="remaining_time"></span> seconds.
   </span> 

   <br/>

   <span style="cursor:pointer; border:solid 1px green; margin:0 10px 0 0;" id="continue_session">Continue the session</span>

  </div>

 </div>

</div>
```

Jquery

```
function logout_with_warning() {

  $.post("_logout_warning.php", function(data_logout_warning) {
  $('#logout_warning_popup').show();
  var time_when_must_logout = new Date().setTime(new Date().getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 2);//2 minutes

  $('#remaining_time').html( '' + Math.round( ( ( parseInt(time_when_must_logout,0) - parseInt((new Date().setTime(new Date().getTime())),0) ) )/1000 ) );

    function updateClock ( ){
    $('#remaining_time').html( '' + Math.round( ( ( parseInt(time_when_must_logout,0) - parseInt((new Date().setTime(new Date().getTime())),0) ) )/1000 ) );
    }
    setInterval( updateClock, (1000*1) );// one second


  });

}
setInterval( logout_with_warning, (60000*3) );
```

Comment: use setTimeout() function or execute clearInterval() before set new timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you call `setInterval` also in the callback of the ajax call, you'll have two `setInterval` calls being active, which both keep invoking the *logout_with_warning* function at regular intervals. After the next ajax call you'll have three doing that...etc.

You can easily fix this by replacing those calls with `setTimeout`, which only call their callback function once.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i want to call function multiple times. And on each call i want to reset timer (`updateClock` function must start to show initial time). Will try with `clearInterval()`

Comment: Of course, but each time you call that function, the next call will be scheduled after the ajax call, so you *do* get a continues flow of function executions. I note however that you do nothing with `logout_with_warning`. I suppose it has some clues about how much time is left...